# ionic http get inside tabs module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to create a simple app that fetches some user data from a get request. I have followed several tutorials and nothing seems to work for me. First, I have created a service like this, called **profile.service.ts**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfileService {

  url = 'https://example.com/api/user';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  getProfile(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

Also, in the **app.module.ts**, I have imported **HttpClientModule**, like this:

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then, on one of my tabs, called **tab1.module.ts** (I use tabs module), I do the following:

```js
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { ProfileService } from '../profile.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule implements OnInit {

  accountData = null;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('test')

    this.profileService.getProfile('3')
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log('my data:', result)
      this.accountData = result
    });
  }

}
```

Finally, I try to print the results in the **tab1.page.html** :

```html
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
      <ion-icon slot="start" color="primary" name="male"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>{{ accountData?.name }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And nothing is printed. Note that it does not work even if I do not use **implements OnInit** in my **Tab1PageModule**. Nothing gets printed in the console either. Is there something wrong because I use the tabs module? Ideally, in the end, I want a different function from profile service to be called for each tab. I use Ionic 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case, for me it worked. For me it looks like you mixed up the tab1.module.ts with tab1.page.ts . The Module is only there to import your packages and lazy load your whole module. It has a different duty then the tab1.page.ts which has a binding to it's .html counterpart. I prepared a Project which worked for me. Checkout especially profile.service.ts, app.module.ts, tab1.module.ts and tab1.page.ts.

[The Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-ylexiz)

I basically took the code and put it into the tab1.page.ts and removed unecessarities.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I added the same code block to tab1.page.ts and it worked.